# Where I can see list of email address which my email registered as their recovery email address?

Tags: email

I need to find the list of services where my email address has been registered as their recovery email address.

I am using Gmail and all other emails also are Gmail, but they are too many and I don't remember many of them I need to see the list of them.

Comment: There's no centralized register for this. The likely answer is that you can't.

Comment: This is like asking, "I want a list of all the people I have talked to at all the parties I have been to." If you didn't keep track, no one else did. Plus this is not a security question. If you want to know the services that have sent you password recovery emails, then that's a simple search in Gmail. And again, it's not a security question.

Comment: Assuming you never delete your mail, try searching your mailboxes. Each one *should* have given you a confirmation email. That's not guaranteed, and your spam filters aren't guaranteed to have let them through, but it's as good as you're going to get.